# Executing multiple updates in a single NHibernate HQL statement

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I would like to write the following SQL in HQL so it executes as a single statement:

```
update child_thingy c
set c.parent_thingy_id = null
where c.common_thingy_id = @common_thingy_id

delete
from parent_thingy p
where p.common_thingy_id = @common_thingy_id
```

I've translated the SQL to HQL as follows:

```
update ChildThingy c
set c.ParentThingy = null
where c.CommonThingy = :commonThingy

delete
from ParentThingy p
where c.ParentThingy = :commonThingy
```

I would like to run this as a single statement, but I can't in a single HQL block using CreateQuery & ExecuteUpdate. I can't run this either in a MultiQuery block and List as I get the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.AggregateQueriesInformation()
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.get_Parameters()
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.CreateCombinedQueryParameters()
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.List()
```

I can't seem to find a MultiQuery equivalent of ExecuteUpdate. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you simply did both in a transaction? It'd be two statements but at least it'd be atomic.

Comment: Already done, but this is more a 'would like to know how to' type of question. In this case it's only 2 statements, but it's conceivable that I'm going to want to do this for more later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem possible (in NH 2.1.2), so had to resort to using CreateSQLQuery and ExecuteUpdate :(